# Adding iframe to dynamic php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I have a trivia php application. The users logon to the app, and then they see a question with a radio button answers.
Each time the user submit an answer, the same page reloads with the next question.
I want to add a timer in order to show the user the time that passed since they logon to the app.
I was thinking about doing it with JavaScript but my problem is that each time the page reloads, the timer restarts to 00:00.
Can I do it with an iFrame? If so, how? If not, I'll be happy to hear about other ways.

Thank you!

Comment: Eventually, I used this: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. Which is a combination of both of your answers. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using iframes these days.

Take a look at using AJAX : [AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp).

You might also want to check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which will make things easier.

The basic idea is that you can make requests from your webpage, then get and process the response without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

var logonTime = "user logon time from PHP";

and then in javascript just calculate the difference from current time and logonTime.